# under which conditions we can say that $Z/mZ \times Z/nZ = Z/nmZ$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a doubt and i don't find the answer i'm asking under which conditions we can say that $Z/mZ \times Z/nZ ≅ Z/nmZ$

I first thought n and m have to be prime with each other, but i found in an exemple G have an order equals to 432000= $60 \times 60 \times 24 \times 5$

then they said $G ≅ Z/60Z \times Z/60Z \times Z/24Z \times Z/5Z $

AND finally $G ≅ Z/60Z \times Z/60Z \times Z/120Z$

I think there is a mistake i agree the last line because of the theorem of classification of abelien finite groupe but i think the first line is not true.
If someone can help me i would be grateful thank you

Comment: You must mean $Z/mnZ$. If so, a necessary and sufficient condition is that they are prime together. The sufficiency of this condition comes from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and the necessity comes from the fact that $Z/mnZ$ has an element of order $mn$ (namely, $1$)

Comment: Also, the groups are not "equal", they're isomorphic.

Comment: @Max yes i mean Z/mnZ

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes isomorphic

Comment: There's no mistake: $\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z$ is a cyclic group of order $mn$, but all groups of order $mnm$ are not cyclic if $m$ and $n$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem is as follows:
$$\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times\mathbb{Z}_{n}\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$$
if and only if $m, n$ are coprime. This is a consequence of [the Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Now in your case both lines are true since $24$ is coprime to $5$.

Comment: thank you so my mistake was to coonsiderate it as a whole

Comment: @FaroukDeutsch Oh, I see. Yes, you can look at pieces, don't have to look at whole group. The isomorphism easily extends to whole $G$ by adding identities on other components. In general if $A\simeq B$ then $C\times A\simeq C\times B$.